# QR code and files?

Tags: php, html, mysql, qr-code

**[TLDR]** I want to enter output from mySQL database, provided from my website hosting service, from each row of data into a separate file in my website directory , which can be referenced by physical, printed QR codes **[TLDR]**

I want to take a set amount of physical, printed QR codes(20 to 30), have them link to my website's files. (for example: QR code ---->  mywebsite.comli.com/file1 ) and be able to add information to these multiple files from mySQL database and also have a function to remove data from these databases and at the same time i remove, send a email to the email inside the file that was removed.

I cant really think of a way to take my data from the database and "put" it into each file. Can i use the redirect operators ( > , >>) to either replace or append the output of the database into the multiple files? But i always get stuck on how to do refer to each possible file exactly. Could reg. expressions come into play?

I am not a coder really, so i had to copy pasta most of my code from online sources. There are probably alot of basic errors/secuirty issues, but i wanted to see if i could just get something working in general, and then fix those afterwards.

Here is the code for my mail_handler.php file, which also connects to the database and prints out the contents in echo statements, but only to the same file.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "email@example.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    // You cannot use header and echo together. It's one or the other.
    }

$servername = "mywebhost.com";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "mydb";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else {
    echo "Succcccessssful concection \n\n";
}

// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),

reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email, message)
VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$from', '$message')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully ";

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


// sql for dispplayying info
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, message FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id:" . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "- email " . $row["email"]. " -message " . $row["message"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}




mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Here is the code for my index.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Form Plant submission</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="mail_handler.php" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why write to these files at all?  Why not have a PHP script serve requests for them by generating the desired output dynamically from the database upon demand?

Comment: as above, generate on demand, cache for later views

Comment: Well, this is for someone else, who wanted optimized workflow while working in a greenhouse. He wanted each QR code to link to a individual person. And since in my database, each row correlated to a person. I Thought it would be optimal to send each output into a separate file, so i can then have a individual "path" for the QR code to link to.

Comment: Yes, the QR codes can still link to individual paths—nothing needs to change there.  The server can just send requests for those paths to a PHP script that generates the response dynamically, from the database content.

Comment: Sorry if this is taking me a while to understand, but are you saying that I can, in each separate file, ask the database for the specific info that i want? Like Steve or Bob? Instead of outputting from the database into files? @eggyal

Comment: @RoSiv  A url does not have to be a path to an actual file on disk. It could be `http:.//website.co.uk/somefile.php?name=steve` Then somefile.php loads to content from the database. You are probably in over your head if this doesnt make sense

Comment: Could you expound on that Steve? I am over my head, but i still want to try and get this to work.  In the example url you gave, could you explain what the ?name=steve part of the path would do or is? And thank you for your help. @Steve

Comment: See [Variables From External Sources](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php): "GET also applies to the *QUERY_STRING* (the information after the '?' in a URL). So, for example, *[http://www.example.com/test.php?id=3](http://www.example.com/test.php?id=3)* contains GET data which is accessible with `$_GET['id']`."